# SSRS - Inserting Next Row's Value into a Previous Row

Tags: reporting-services

How would one go about changing the report into this format?

For example, I have data here that I want to change so that I merge the duplicate rows.

So I want to move the first value of the number column into the account field, move the second value into the first row value, and hide the duplicate row.

Example:
Columns from the query are account, combo, type, number
Columns that are going to be on the report are account, combo

Sample row data from query (account,combo,type,number):

abc, (blank), zxc, 456

abc, (blank), zxv, 789

What I want for the row data to display on the report (account,combo):

456, 789

I've hidden the rows so that only one row appears in the Visibility Tab.
=iif(Fields!Account.Value = Previous(Fields!Account.Value), True, False)

I've insert this expression into the Account Field and returns the correct value.
=iif(Fields!Type.Value="zxc", Fields!Number.Value, Fields!Account.Value)

But I can't seem to get the Next Row's number value inserted into the previous record's combo column.

Any ideas whether if SSRS is capable of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What specific version of SSRS is this?

Comment: I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and using SQL Server 2008 R2.